# Retry SFTP if it fails?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I am using SSH.NET to upload. But I want to retry to sftp the file if the process fails. I have this code but I don't think this is the best way to handle a retry. What would be the best way to go about handling this?

```
var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
int retryCount = 3;

for (int retry = 0; retry < retryCount; retry++)
{
    try
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

        var client = new SftpClient("ftp.site.com", 22, "userName", "password");

        client.Connect();

        if (client.IsConnected)
        {
            var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                client.UploadFile(fileStream, "/fileshare/" + fileName, null);

                client.Disconnect();
                client.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Add(ex);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    if (exceptions.Count == 3)
    {
        throw exceptions[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: For a solution without additional dependencies, see [Automatically resume SFTP download after network connection is restored with SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44139122/850848).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended approach for retries is transient-fault-handling library [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
  .Handle<Exception>()
  .WaitAndRetry(3, retryAttempt => 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)) 
  );

retryPolicy.Execute(() => {
    using (var client = new SftpClient("ftp.site.com", 22, "userName", "password")) 
    {
        /* file uploading .. */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the source code of the `Connect` method](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/34ce2bd1d0eb7dc68f8ad5a68f407f66d774f9ed/src/Renci.SshNet/BaseClient.cs#L197) then you can see it has documentation comments about the exceptions. Unfortunately none of them mentions the error message which you are facing.

As you have stated in the comments you don't know which exception is thrown, because your logging system captures only the exception's message. Your suspects are `SSHException` and `SshConnectionException`.

In case of Polly you could define a retry policy in multiple ways for this situtation

1. Using a single `Handle` builder method

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
      .Handle<Exception>(ex => ex is SSHException || ex is SshConnectionException)
      .WaitAndRetry(...);
```

2. Using a `Handle` and an `Or` builder methods

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
      .Handle<SSHException>()
      .Or<SshConnectionException>()
      .WaitAndRetry(...);
```

3. If the thrown exception is not any of the suspected ones
   then you could define your policy in a less type-safe way

```
const string ErrorPrefix = "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host";
var retryPolicy = Policy
      .Handle<Exception>(ex => ex.Message.StartsWith(ErrorPrefix) 
          || (ex.InnerException?.Message.StartsWith(ErrorPrefix) ?? false))
      .WaitAndRetry(...);
```

---

You have also mentioned that

> the maximum execution time allowed for function app is 5 minutes

Polly's retry allows you to define at most how many times you want to perform the same action:

- *N* times: this can be achieved by using the `Retry` or `WaitAndRetry` builder methods
- *Infinite* times: this can be achieved by using the `RetryForever` or `WaitAndRetryForever` builder methods

If you want to perform retry attempts for a given timeframe then you need to combine a Retry and a Timeout policies.

```
var timeoutPolicy = Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4.5));
var retryPolicy = Policy
      .Handle...
      .WaitAndRetryForever(...);
var combinedPolicy = Policy.Wrap(timeoutPolicy, retryPolicy);
```

Please bear in mind that the order of the `Wrap` method's parameters matter:

- Timeout, Retry: Here the timeout is global which means it overarches all retry attempts
- Retry, Timeout: Here the timeout is local which means it is applied for each retry attempt separately

This flexibility allows you to define a per retry attempt and an overall time constraints as well

```
var globalTimeoutPolicy = Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4.5));
var perAttemptTimeoutPolicy = Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var retryPolicy = Policy
      .Handle...
      .WaitAndRetryForever(...);
var combinedPolicy = Policy.Wrap(globalTimeoutPolicy, retryPolicy, perAttemptTimeoutPolicy);
```